# Override ActionScript Effect

Tags: actionscript

I am looking to have an mp3 start playing whenever an item fades in. These items fade in at different times based on a `startDelay` value. It seems to me that the best way to have the mp3 start playing on the fade in would be to extend the `spark.effects.Fade` class, override the `play` function, and then have the mp3 play when `play` is called (which I assumed would be after `startDelay` is done), but this isn't working. Any ideas?

```
public class FadeWithMusic extends Fade
{
    public function FadeWithMusic(target:Object=null)
    {
        super(target);
    }

    override public function play(targets:Array = null,
                                     playReversedFromEnd:Boolean = false):
                                     Array /* of EffectInstance */
    {
        var returnedValue:Array = super.play(targets, playReversedFromEnd);

        var sound:Sound = new Sound();
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("urlString");
        sound.load(urlReq);
        sound.play();

        return returnedValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Use timer to make sound delay.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import spark.effects.Fade;

    public class FadeWithMusic extends Fade
    {
        private var soundTimer : Timer;

        public function FadeWithMusic(target : Object = null)
        {
            super(target);
        }

        private function playSound(event : TimerEvent) : void
        {
            var sound : Sound = new Sound();
            var urlReq : URLRequest = new URLRequest("1.mp3");
            sound.load(urlReq);
            sound.play();
        }

        override public function play(targets : Array = null, playReversedFromEnd : Boolean = false) : Array /* of EffectInstance */
        {
            soundTimer = new Timer(startDelay, 1);
            soundTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playSound, false, 0, true);
            soundTimer.start();
            return super.play(targets, playReversedFromEnd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's definitely played, but only immediately at the beginning of the whole script. If I have `fade.startDelay = 10000; fade.play([label]);`, I would expect the sound to play after 10000 ms. Instead, it plays when `label` is added to the canvas.

Comment: Also, I've tried writing my own `start()` method (can't override - private), since I think `play` calls `start` when the `startDelay` is up.